# Clean way to format flags checks

Tags: c++, c, flags

I have an enum like (this is just an example):

```
enum tStates
{
    STOP            = (1<<0),
    PLAYING         = (1<<1),
    SYNCHRONISING       = (1<<2),
    READY_TO_PLAY       = (1<<3),
    CONNECTED       = (1<<4),
}
```

So it can be playing and connected at the same time etc... Multiple states at once is possible.
I need to test different states, for instance:

```
if (m_pDeviceHealth->getHealth().isSet(PLAYING))
{


}
else if (m_pDeviceHealth->getHealth().isSet(STOP))
{


}
```

It tends to become quite big and difficult to read.

Is there a clearer way to check for a flag? Is it possible to use a switch for instance?

Comment: How about bitwise OR? E.g. `CONNECTED | SYNCHRONISING`

Comment: Check out [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c) for bitwise operators

Comment: I spy, with my little eye... tabs for alignment! Naughty @dyesdyes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I don't know how the actual flag checking should be made simpler without your data structures or what you want to do with that. Basically what you have is:

```
if (m_pDeviceHealth->getHealth().isSet(PLAYING))
    | your expression           |      |your flag|
```

Seems quite minimal to me. For different flags you'll obviously need different if branches.
If you are looking for checking if any of multiple bits is set, you can use bit masking like:

```
if (m_pDeviceHealth->getHealth() & (PLAYING | SYNCHRONIZING))
```

under the assumption that getHealth is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not nice but if you are looking for a `switch`, you can do flag combination yourself in `case`s:

```
switch (m_pDeviceHealth->getHealth().getValue()) {
   case PLAYING:
      // ...
      break;
   case STOP:
      // ...
      break;
   case CONNECTED:
   case SYNCHRONISING:
   case SYNCHRONISING|CONNECTED:
      // ...
      break;
}
```

Comment: Is it even going to work as it's supposed to check only one bit?

Comment: Did you even bother to try this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what's wrong? I think he wanted to point out that you can use bitwise operators in `case` statements like `case SYNCHRONISING|CONNECTED`. But I think it's not really 'clean' ...

Comment: I wrote that it is not nice - you need to have case for every possible combination of flags. So, if PLAYING can be combined with CONNECTED then you need to have case for PLAYING|CONNECTED.

But questions asks for switch - here is a switch

Comment: @OlegFedorov: Heh, well, fair enough ;)

Comment: Your code doesn't do exactly what his does, since if `PLAYING` is set, he won't test any of the other cases.  To do this in a switch, you'd have to start with all of the combinations which contain `PLAYING` (followed by the action and a `break`), then all of the combinations which contain `STOP`, but don't contain `PLAYING`, and so on.